# MIPS: How do multiple BEQ statements work?

Tags: assembly, mips, qtspim

I am new to MIPS assembly language and have ran into a few issues over the past few days, while I have worked through most of them myself, this one in particular has me stumped.

I am programming a simple calculator, and I have 2 **b**ranch **eq**uals statements in my script, to my understanding the way a beq statement is written like so:

beq $t0, $t1, additionFunction

Which roughly translates to:

If $t0 is equal to $t1, jump to additionFunction in the script.

Here is my code:

```
.data #Data section
Prompt1: .asciiz    "For addition enter 1
                    \nFor subtraction enter 2
                    \nFor and enter 3
                    \nFor or enter 4
                    \nFor xor enter 5
                    \nEnter your choice: "
Prompt2: .asciiz "\nEnter first number: "
Prompt3: .asciiz "\nEnter second number: "
Result: .asciiz "The result is: "
.globl main
.text #Code section

main:
li $t1, 1
li $t2, 2

#STARTUP MESSAGE
li $v0, 4 #system call code for Print String
la $a0, Prompt1 #load address of Prompt1 into $a0
syscall #print the Prompt1 message

li $v0, 5 #system call code for Read Integer
syscall #reads the value of 1st integer into $v0
move $t0, $v0 #move the 1st integer to $t0

beq $t0, $t1, additionFunction #if branch is equal to $t1
beq $t0, $t2, subtractionFunction

additionFunction:
li $v0, 4 #call to print string
la $a0, Prompt2 #load prompt2 into variable $a0
syscall #call system to print

li $v0, 5 #call to read integer
syscall #read integer into $v0
move $s1, $v0                        

li $v0, 4 #syscall to print string
la $a0, Prompt3 #load prompt3 into variable $a0
syscall #call system to print

li $v0, 5 #call to read integer into $v0
syscall #read integer into $v0
move $s2, $v0 #moves value of $v0 to $t2

li $v0, 4 #syscall to print string
la $a0, Result #load Result into variable $a0
syscall #call system to print

add $s3, $s1, $s2 #t3 = t2 +t1
li $v0, 1 #call to print integer
move $a0, $s3
syscall

Exit

subtractionFunction: #if branch is equal to $t2
li $v0, 4 #call to print string
la $a0, Prompt2 #load prompt2 into variable $a0
syscall #call system to print

li $v0, 5 #call to read integer
syscall #read integer into $v0
move $s1, $v0                        

li $v0, 4 #syscall to print string
la $a0, Prompt3 #load prompt3 into variable $a0
syscall #call system to print

li $v0, 5 #call to read integer into $v0
syscall #read integer into $v0
move $s2, $v0 #moves value of $v0 to $t2

li $v0, 4 #syscall to print string
la $a0, Result #load Result into variable $a0
syscall #call system to print

sub $s3, $s1, $s2 #t3 = t2 +t1
li $v0, 1 #call to print integer
move $a0, $s3
syscall

Exit
```

Upon entering "1" in the first prompt, the program runs correctly and adds the next two integers the user types in. However, upon entering "2", I am given the following error message:

> Instruction references undefined symbol at 0x00400048 [0x00400048]     0x110a0000 beq $8, $10, 0 [subtractionFunction-0x00400048]; 23: beq $t0, $t2, subtractionFunction

From my understanding this means that I have an incorrect beq statement, and I'm confused as to why, and what would I have to change to get the function to work properly?

I am very new to MIPS assembly language, so if this is a simple fix I apologize in advance for what could be a seemingly pointless question, but I'd appreciate any type of feedback to help me better understand this language.

Thanks.

Comment: The code looks fine from a quick glance. We don't know what `Exit` does, make sure that does not stop assembling of the rest of the file.

Comment: @Jester Thank you, removing "exit" worked, I instead created a jump statement to end the program at the end of the file.